# C compiler asserts: how to dynamically use them wherever the expression is fixed?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, assert

My code makes extensive use of compiler asserts like this to flag errors at build time in preference to run time, and to improve performance by not executing asserts at run time.

```
#define COMPILER_ASSERT(EXPR)    switch (0) {case 0: case (EXPR):;}
```

All good.  I'd like to extend this to use compiler asserts for the following case.  Say I have a macro which is called from 100 places, 99 of which pass a fixed value, 1 of which passes a variable.  How can I code the macro to make this a compiler assert in 99 places and a runtime assert in the last one.

If I could guarantee that MY_FUNCTION() was always called with a fixed value I could code it like this.

```
void my_function(int x)
{
  //do something
}

#define MY_FUNCTION(X) \
  COMPILER_ASSERT(X != 0); \
  my_function(X)

//These can all take advantage of a compiler assert.
MY_FUNCTION(1);
MY_FUNCTION(SOME_HASH_DEFINE);
MY_FUNCTION(sizeof(SOME_STRUCTURE));
//This can't (this is a contrived example - actual code is complex).
int some_variable = 1;
MY_FUNCTION(some_variable);
```

So, if I can't guarantee that X is fixed, but want to take advantage for each call to MY_FUNCTION() where it is, how do I code it?  Something like:

```
#define MY_FUNCTION(X) \
  if (X is a fixed value) COMPILER_ASSERT(X != 0); \
  else assert(X != 0); \ 
  my_function(X)
```

Recoding the calls to MY_FUNCTION() to only pass fixed values is not an option for me.  Yes I could define MY_FUNCTION_FIXED_X and MY_FUNCTION_VARIABLE_X but that exposes all this to the calling code.

Thanks for your help.
NickB

Comment: Maybe you could use C11, which has real compile-time asserts ?

Comment: When you say fixed , do you mean compile time constant? If yes, I imagine value would be different in the 99 calls in client code, is that right?

Comment: Correct.  One example is where the value passed to MY_FUNCTION(X) must be in a specific range of integers, and I want to assert that X is in range.

Comment: Do you know the range of integers which should have compile time assertion?

Comment: No.  This is just one (simplified) example.  In some cases I will have a group of #defined constants, which the callers pass to MY_FUNCTION(), and I want the compiler assert to check they are in range.  In other cases the caller might be passing a size, where MY_FUNCTION is doing an allocation or copy, and it just wants to sanity check that X isn't zero or above some large threshold, etc.  But if you can offer a solution for a specific case where the valid range is, say 1-20, that would be a great start.

Answer (score 2):

If your C compiler supports variable-length arrays, you can write something like:

```
#define GENERIC_ASSERT(EXPR) \
  ((EXPR) ? (void) 0 : assert((EXPR)), (void) sizeof(char[(EXPR) ? 1 : -1]))
```

If `EXPR` is a false-valued compile time constant, this reduces to:

```
(assert((EXPR)), (void) sizeof(char[-1]))
```

which is a compile error (it involves a negative-length array).

If `EXPR` is a true-valued compile time constant, we get:

```
((void) 0), (void) 1)
```

Both Clang and gcc are capable of reducing the assert to nothing if invoked with a true-valued compile time constant.

If `EXPR` has a runtime value, the `sizeof` expression if invoked would result in a runtime error (e.g. an abort), so the `assert` is sequenced first through the use of the comma operator.

Unfortunately in the compile-time constant case, the error message output by gcc is not particularly illuminating:

```
prog.c:5: error: size of array ‘type name’ is negative
```

In Clang it's a bit better:

```
error: array size is negative
  GENERIC_ASSERT(2 + 2 == 5);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: expanded from:
  ((EXPR) ? (void) 0 : assert((EXPR)), (void) sizeof(char[(EXPR) ? 1 : -1]))
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I was after.  I'm looking for something that will compile into a compiler assert if the expression is fixed and only compile to a runtime assert if the expression is variable, so giving the best runtime performance by eliminating from executable code any assert whose result is known at compile time.

Comment: @NickB if `EXPR` is a compile time constant, the `assert` is in a non-reachable branch (since `EXPR` is true, the `(void) 0` branch is taken) so the above will compile down to an empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
#define MY_FUNCTION(X) \
  do{ \
if (X>=1 && X<=20) {\
COMPILER_ASSERT(X != 0); \
my_function(X);\
}\ // end if block
  // you can use break here too
  else myfunction2(X,__FILE__,__LINE__); \ // this will be the runtime assert
 }while (0);


void myfunction2(int x, const char * file, const int line)
{ 
// print here information
exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In P99 I have this macro for static asserts

```
# if p99_has_feature(c_static_assert)
#  define static_assert _Static_assert
# else
#  define static_assert(EXPR, DIAGSTR)                            \
extern char const p00_compiletime_assert[                         \
 sizeof((void const*[3*(!!(EXPR)) - 1]){                          \
    &p00_compiletime_assert,                                      \
   "static assertion failed: " P99_STRINGIFY(EXPR) ", " DIAGSTR}) \
]
extern char const p00_compiletime_assert[sizeof(void const*[2])];
# endif
#endif
```

this has the advantage that you can use it almost everywhere, at least with C99, where a declaration can be used. (C99 allows to mix statements and declarations) So this can be used inside a function block of any kind, or in file scope provided that `EXPR` is a compile time integer constant.